# Function holomorphic in the neighb. of zero, bounded by exponent is equal 0

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

I want to prove that if $f$ is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $0$ and $|f(\frac{1}{n})| \le \frac{1}{e^n}$ for $n$ sufficiently big, then $f =0$.

I know that if $f$ is holomorphic in a neighb. of zero, then it has the form $f(\frac{1}{x}) = \sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)} (0)}{n! x^n}$

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-x} = 1-x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6} +\cdots 
= \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^n} {n!}$$

I thought I could use the identity principle which says that if $f,g \in \mathcal{O}(\Omega), \ f=g $ on $A \subset \Omega$ s.t. $A' \cap \Omega \neq \emptyset$, then $f=g$ on $\Omega$, but I have trouble determining the set $A$ in this case.

Could you help me a bit?

Comment: Try showing that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I don't think the identity principle can directly be used to prove this, as you are trying to do.

Comment: So I should prove that $|f|$ has a local maximum in the neighb. of zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $f$ is continuous at $z=0$, and
$$
\left|\,\,f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,\right|\le \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^n},
$$
then $\,f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)=0$. If we assume that $f\not\equiv 0$, then $f$ is expressed as
$$
f(z)=z^mg(z),
$$
where $m$ is a positive integer and $g$ an entire function with $g(0)\ne 0$.
But then we would have that
$$
\left|\,\,f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,\right|=\frac{1}{n^m}\left|\,g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,\right|\le \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^n},
$$
and hence
$$
\left|\,g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,\right|\le \frac{n^m}{\mathrm{e}^n},
$$
which means that $\,\lim_{n\to\infty} g\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)=0$, and as $g$ is continuous at $z=0$, then $g(0)=0$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I have corrected it.